# Environment Error while installing OpenCV in windows through pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BeGK.png)
I am trying to install openCV for windows. But I keep getting the following error :

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory:
>   *C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-vfx6an4h\e91a5c7a04ed7f6b813b6ebe4c4eddb2cf610ac6d97a6256c8c8f3ef*

I am using AMD 64 bit processor with Windows 10 and python 3.5.2[MSC v.1900 64bit (AMD64)] on win32

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package by opening powershell in administrator mode.